# Javascript : eliminate array element with two array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

For example I have two arrays like this.

```
const data = ["John", "Andy", "Ruby"]
const eliminator = ["John"]
```

So I expect a result like :

```
data = ["Andy", "Ruby"]
```

I'm so new with javascript. It would be appreciated if the answer is in plain javascript, but advanced answer are very welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) and [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) (that returns **true** or **false**) makes the code shorter.

```js
const data = ["John", "Andy", "Ruby"]
const eliminator = ["John"]

var newData = data.filter(o=>!eliminator.includes(o))

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is the simplest answer and easy understand

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.filter()` to filter the values of `data` array that do not present in `eliminator` array.

```js
const data = ["John", "Andy", "Ruby"]
const eliminator = ["John"]
var res = data.filter(name => eliminator.indexOf(name) === -1);
console.log(res);
```

You can use the simple function declarations if you expect it to work in all browsers. Also note that you need to use `indexOf()` and not `includes()` method as `includes()` do not work in IE browsers.

```js
const data = ["John", "Andy", "Ruby"]
const eliminator = ["John"]
var res = data.filter(function(name){
   return eliminator.indexOf(name) === -1;
});
console.log(res);
```

For further reading you can refer here: [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I'm not a downvoter : ) I just want to add that OP question have the tag nodejs  so I think the issue with  IE browsers and `includes()` doesn't matters. nodejs supports `includes()` from version 6.0.0.

Comment: @Emeeus yes, that does not but there are several cases when OP tags Nodejs but they also tend to use as in front end HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this functionality all over the project, You can add the diff prototype in array class.

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(eli) {
   return this.filter(function(i) {return eli.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};
```

After that you can use this method any where...

```
data.diff(eliminator)
```

Gives you the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) `_.difference()`

```
const data = ["John", "Andy", "Ruby"];
const eliminator = ["John"];

var NewData = _.difference(data , eliminator);

// Result : NewData = ["Andy", "Ruby"]
```